# Making a list of dataframes which are a subset of one dataframe using R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I have one dataframe, and I would like to make a list of dataframes, each of which is a subset of this original data, based on the value of one variable.

I have found this answer on CrossValidated
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161414/creating-subsets-of-dataframes-from-a-single-dataframe-based-on-the-distinct-val
It looks like he's applying a different function to create his new dataframes than I would like to, and I'm not sure how to make this work for what I would like to do.

Here is the example of what I would like to do:

```
months <- c(0:35)
product<- c(112:147)
index <- rnorm(36)
data <- data.frame(months, product, index)

subfun<-function(x,y,z) { subset(x,y>=z & y<=z+12) }

for(i in 1:24)
{ 
  assign(paste("dataset",i-1,i+11,sep=""),subfun(data, data$months,i-1))
  i=i+1
}
```

This gives me 26 separate dataframes, each with a unique name. I would like to have these as a list, so I can use lapply to apply a regression function to each separate dataframe (dataset012:dataset236).

Is anyone able to tell me how I can make a list of dataframes from the outset? I don't want to create all the dataframes separately, but instead create a list of dataframes when I do the subsetting.

I hope this is clear, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: `lapply(1:24, function(x) subfun(data, data$months, x-1) )` - is that enough?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thank you. Do you know how I can assign each of the dataframes in the list a unique name?

Comment: You could wrap the lapply in `setNames` and provide the names in the second argument. Otherwise, use `names(myList) <- c(...)` where myList is the list returned by `lapply`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, much appreciated.